# Hausdorff dimension of sum of sets

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

Assume $0<r_0<n$. Are there sets $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, such that the Hasudorff dimension of $A,B$ are zero, But $\dim_H(A+B)=r_0$?

When $r_0$ is integer, I have found(By attention to page 104,the example 7.8 of the book FRACTAL
GEOMETRY
Mathematical Foundations
and Applications, version 2,Kenneth Falconer ) the $A,B$ with the above property. But when $r_0$ is not integer, I don't know how to find these sets?

Comment: I think this is possible, by a twist of the method in Falconer's book.